# csv reservation download AIRBNB

Tags: python

Hi i'm trying to download the reservation.csv file of airbnb but i don't know how to send the get method with authentications, can someone please help me?.

I know that at some point i need to authenticate but i don't know when and how

My code so far:

```py
import requests

req = requests.get('www.airbnb.com/api/v2/download_reservations?_a_lot_of_stuff')
url_content = req.content

csv_file = open('downloaded.csv', 'wb')
csv_file.write(url_content)
csv_file.close()
```

As a result i get this:

```json
{
  "error_code":401,
  "error":"authentication_required",
  "error_message":"idiot_go_play_mario_kart"
}
```

Comment: You need to provide authentication headers. Airbnb won't just respond to any request without verifying the identity of the sender. Also the response is JSON, not CSV.

Comment: @Gaberocksall , sorry im new, i'm just tryig to find a way of downloading my reservation report without paying a monthly susbscription, but i think is a little bit out of my knowledge. if anybody can help me out please contact me it will be great